# How can I map Result<(), E> into a numeric error code?

Tags: rust

I have a bunch of FFI functions that I call using C. The caller expects 1 for success, or -1 on failure.

```rust
struct Error;

fn my_rust_function() -> Result<(), Error> {
    Ok(())
}

#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub extern "C" fn Called_From_C() -> i32 {
    let result = my_rust_function();

    match result {
        Ok(_) => 1,
        Err(_) => -1,
    }
}
```

Is there a more idiomatic way of converting my `Result<(), Error>` into the 1 / -1 return code?

Comment: That's how I'd do it — it's clear what is being performed. You could do `result.map(|_| 1).map_err(|_| -1).unwrap()`, but then you're creating needless closures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create an *extension trait*:

```
trait FfiError {
    fn as_c_error(&self) -> i32;
}

impl<T, E> FfiError for Result<T, E> {
    fn as_c_error(&self) -> i32 {
        match self {
            Ok(_) => 1,
            Err(_) => -1,
        }
    }
}
```

Once it's brought into scope, you can call it like any other method:

```
pub extern "C" fn called_from_c() -> i32 {
    my_rust_function().as_c_error()
}
```

See also:

- [Is there a way other than traits to add methods to a type I don't own?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33376486/155423)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`repr(transparent)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html#reprtransparent) to create a type where you could implement [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) and that still represent a `i32`, this allow to compile check that you transform your result correctly assuming you didn't have bug in your `from()` implementation so maybe add some unit tests.

```rust
type MyResult = Result<(), ()>;

fn my_rust_function() -> MyResult {
    Ok(())
}

#[repr(transparent)]
pub struct CResult {
    code: i32,
//    code: libc::c_int, // if your C lib expect a `c_int` and not a `i32`
}

impl From<MyResult> for CResult {
    fn from(result: MyResult) -> Self {
        let code = match result {
            Ok(_) => 1,
            Err(_) => -1,
        };
        Self { code }
    }
}

#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub extern "C" fn Called_From_C() -> CResult {
    let result = my_rust_function();

    result.into()
}
```

---

You could also use `enum` with [`repr(i32)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html#repru-repri):

```rust
#[repr(i32)]
pub enum CResult {
    NoError = 1,
    Error = -1,
}

impl From<MyResult> for CResult {
    fn from(result: MyResult) -> Self {
        match result {
            Ok(_) => CResult::NoError,
            Err(_) => CResult::Error,
        }
    }
}
```

---

In nightly, you could also implement [`Try`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Try.html):

```rust
#![feature(try_trait)]
use std::ops::Try;

type MyResult = Result<(), ()>;

fn my_rust_function() -> MyResult {
    Ok(())
}

#[repr(i32)]
pub enum CResult {
    NoError = 1,
    Error = -1,
}

impl From<MyResult> for CResult {
    fn from(result: MyResult) -> Self {
        match result {
            Ok(_) => CResult::NoError,
            Err(_) => CResult::Error,
        }
    }
}

impl From<CResult> for MyResult {
    fn from(cresult: CResult) -> Self {
        match cresult {
            CResult::NoError => Ok(()),
            CResult::Error => Err(()),
        }
    }
}

impl Try for CResult {
    type Ok = ();
    type Error = ();

    fn into_result(self) -> MyResult {
        self.into()
    }

    fn from_ok(_: <Self as Try>::Ok) -> Self {
        Self::NoError
    }

    fn from_error(_: <Self as Try>::Error) -> Self {
        Self::Error
    }
}

#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub extern "C" fn Called_From_C() -> CResult {
    let _ = my_rust_function()?;

    CResult::NoError
}
```

---

Note: Be careful with the enumeration one, make sure your implementation is compatible. `#[repr(libc::c_int)]` is what we really want but I don't know any way to express this in Rust. So maybe a structure with `repr(transparent)` is more safe if the lib expect a `c_int`.

Comment: Why is `#[repr(transparent)]` necessary? It wouldn't affect how you'd write the code, and I'm fairly certain the compiler makes that optimization anyways.

Comment: @jhpratt Because it would be UB without https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1758-repr-transparent.md

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I had not thought of creating an enum but it's a very neat solution. I marked @shepmaster response as the answer, because it is closest in spirit to what I'm trying to achieve.