# What design pattern does the SNAFU library use to extend external types?

Tags: design-patterns, rust, idioms

I've been playing around with the interesting [SNAFU library](https://docs.rs/crate/snafu/0.5.0).

A slightly modified and stand-alone example from the SNAFU page is as below:

```rust
use snafu::{ResultExt, Snafu};
use std::{fs, io, path::PathBuf};

#[derive(Debug, Snafu)]
enum Error {
    #[snafu(display("Unable to read configuration from {}: {}", path.display(), source))]
    ReadConfiguration { source: io::Error, path: PathBuf },
}

type Result<T, E = Error> = std::result::Result<T, E>;

fn process_data() -> Result<()> {
    let path = "config.toml";
    let read_result: std::result::Result<String, io::Error> = fs::read_to_string(path);    
    let _configuration = read_result.context(ReadConfiguration { path })?;
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let foo = process_data();

    match foo {
        Err(e) => println!("Hello {}", e),
        _ => println!("success")
    }
}
```

The change I've made is to make the type on the `Result` from `fs::read_to_string(path)` explicit in `process_data()`.

Given this, I can't understand how `read_result` has the `context` method available to it, as the `std::result::Result` docs don't make any reference to context (and the compiler similarly complains if you strip out the SNAFU stuff and try to access context).

There is a pattern being used here that is not obvious to me. My naive understanding is that external types cannot be extended because of the orphan rules, but something is happening here that looks much like such an extension.

I'm also confused by the `type Result...` line. I'm aware of type aliasing, but not using the syntax in which the left hand side has a generic assigned. Clearly, this is an important part of the design pattern.

My request is for clarification as to what pattern is being used here and how it works. It seems to get at some pretty interesting aspects of Rust. Further reading would be valued!

Comment: I'm glad you like it!

Comment: @Shepmaster yes, it has a very elegant API!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ResultExt`](https://docs.rs/snafu/0.5.0/snafu/trait.ResultExt.html) is an *extension trait*, which is why it uses the somewhat common suffix `Ext`.

Reduced, the implementation contains the definition of the trait and a small handful of implementations of the trait for specific types (or just one):

```
pub trait ResultExt<T, E>: Sized {
    fn context<C, E2>(self, context: C) -> Result<T, E2>
    where
        C: IntoError<E2, Source = E>,
        E2: std::error::Error + ErrorCompat;
}

impl<T, E> ResultExt<T, E> for std::result::Result<T, E> {
    fn context<C, E2>(self, context: C) -> Result<T, E2>
    where
        C: IntoError<E2, Source = E>,
        E2: std::error::Error + ErrorCompat,
    {
        self.map_err(|error| context.into_error(error))
    }
}
```

By importing `ResultExt`, you bring the trait and its methods into scope. The library has implemented them for the `Result` type, so you are able to make use of them as well.

See also:

- [Is there a way other than traits to add methods to a type I don't own?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33376486/155423)

> I'm aware of type aliasing, but not using the syntax in which the left hand side has a generic assigned. Clearly, this is an important part of the design pattern.

It's not important for the ability to use `.context()`, it's just a practice I encourage. Most custom `Result` aliases shadow the name `Result` (e.g. [`std::io::Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/type.Result.html)), which means if you need to use a different error type, you need to use ugly full paths or another alias (e.g. `type StdResult<T, E> = std::result::Result<T, E>`).

By creating the local alias `Result` with a *default generic*, the user can  type `Result<T>` instead of the more verbose `Result<T, MyError>`, but can still use `Result<T, SomeOtherError>` when needed. Sometimes, I'll even go further and define a default type for the success type. This is most common in unit tests:

```
mod test {
    type Result<T = (), E = Box<dyn std::error::Error>> = std::result::Result<T, E>;

    fn setup() -> Result<String> {
        Ok(String::new())
    }

    fn special() -> Result<String, std::io::Error> {
        std::fs::read_to_string("/etc/hosts")
    }

    #[test]
    fn x() -> Result {
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So snafu _is_ extending `std::result::Result`, and to get around the orphan rules it is necessary to import `ResultExt` so the extension trait exists in the local scope.