# Why does Rust syntactically separate the data definition of a type from function and method implementations?

Tags: types, rust, syntax

Object-oriented languages like C++ and Java use objects to define behaviour for specific data. Because their meanings are closely related, they are declared in the same context: the class.

Rust chose to separate them syntactically.

C++ style:

```cpp
class Foo {
    public:
        int get_bar();
    private:
        int _bar;
}
```

Rust style:

```rust
struct Foo {
    bar: i8,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn bar() -> i8 {
        bar
    }
}
```

Isn't Rust an Object Oriented language ?

Comment: You compare a class with a struct. You should maybe compare rust structs with structs in another language. Rust doesn't really try to look OOP.

Comment: @DenysSéguret That is / should be the answer, I think... Rust was never meant to be OOP (same as many other newer languages)

Comment: Trait implementations are explicit, which allows you to do things like: `impl<T> Foo for T where T: Bar + Baz {}`. I guess inherent methods follow the same syntax for consistency. Also, from a more philosophical point of view, data and functions are separate things, and Rust is not an OOP language which mixes the two together.

Comment: This question is opinion based. So here's my opinion: What matters most usually is the data, not the functions or algorithms. Devise a proper data structure and you solved most problems. Devise a bad one and no implementation will save it. It thus make sense to separate the struct (or structs, as one is rarely alone). OOP languages are usually based on the opposite idea that the facade makes the essence.

Comment: [The Rust Programming Language](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1718500440) book includes a chapter on [Object Oriented Programming Features of Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-00-oop.html) that may be relevant.

Comment: Also note that Java has recently added its own version of structs, called [Records](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html), in an effort to better support Functional Programming. Nearly all languages today are multi-paradigm. Despite Java marketing itself as an OO language, most of the Java code I've seen is still Procedural, i.e. Services and DTOs, so it shouldn't be surprising that languages are formally shifting away from a paradigm that enterprises never really adopted anyway.

Comment: IMO, if Rust is or is not an OO language has **nothing** to do with the choices of syntax.

Comment: This question is **not** opinion based.  I hope it's just reopened as-is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In languages like C++ or Java, the set of methods that a type implements is fixed when the type is defined. That means that a single syntactical construct is sufficient to express the two related concepts.

In Rust, you can implement a trait for a type without the original implementing code ever knowing about it. This *requires* that there be syntax for implementing the trait separately from the data definition. Once that requirement is present, it's less confusing to use the same syntax universally, even within a single file.

Crate 1:

```rust
struct Foo;
```

Crate 2:

```rust
trait Price {
    fn price(&self) -> u8;
}

impl Price for crate1::Foo {
    fn price(&self) -> u8 {
        42
    }
}
```

Additionally, implementing multiple traits for the same type may result in name collisions of the methods. Separating out each trait's implementation into a separate syntax block clearly disambiguates which methods are being implemented.

See also:

- [Is there a way other than traits to add methods to a type I don't own?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33376486/155423)

Comment: C# has extension methods while following the same class/method style as Java.

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed do you know if C# was _designed_ to have extension methods? My understanding is that it was not. That would indicate that C# has both styles for backwards compatibility reasons, not greenfield design reasons.

Comment: Kotlin definitely was designed to have extension methods and still follows Java's style for non-extension methods. Of course, in that case familiarity to Java users and easy porting of Java code is one of priority design goals.