# Implement a new .clean() method on String

Tags: rust

I'd like to be able to take a string and call a method on it like so:

```rust
let s = String::new();
s.clean()
```

I figured I'd implement it as a trait for Strings, and so started writing this:

```rust
trait Clean {
    fn clean(&mut self) -> Self {
        return self.trim_start_matches("\"");
    }
}

impl Clean for String {}
```

This has at least 2 problems with it:

1. because self can be anything, there's no guarantee that it has the `.trim_start_matches()` method - and so Rust won't compile.
2. looking at the signature of the `.trim_start_matches()`, I don't think it mutates in place, so I don't think that appending .clean() to the end would work (I'd have to create a new variable)

What's the correct way to implement this?

Apologies if this has been asked before, I couldn't figure out what to put into the search bar to find similar answers.

Comment: on your case I would do something like that https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=908bba01fb878f0f82f9be0207ed0557 I think implement a clean method on String that only make in a specific context is not clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way other than traits to add methods to a type I don't own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376486/is-there-a-way-other-than-traits-to-add-methods-to-a-type-i-dont-own)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the actual implementation to the `impl` block. There, you do know the type of `self`.

```rust
trait Clean {
    fn clean(&self) -> Self;
}

impl Clean for String {
    fn clean(&self) -> Self {
        // to_owned() to go from &str to String, so you can chain String methods
        self.trim_start_matches("\"").to_owned()
    }
}
```

Comment: wow so simple... should have thought of it:) thanks